# How can i make my randomly moving object move in a specific angle in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, simulation, trigonometry, angle

[Full Code](https://github.com/salzig1/ant_simulation/blob/phero/main.py)

```
self.VEL = 3
self.RAND = numpy.linspace(-self.VEL, +self.VEL, 100)  # calculating value between -2 and 2, a total of 100 values
-----------------------------------------
if self.new_line:
    self.deltax = random.choice(self.RAND)
    self.deltay = random.choice(self.RAND)
    self.new_line = False
self.move(self.deltax, self.deltay)
-----------------------------------------
def move(self, deltax, deltay):
    self.x += deltax
    self.y += deltay
```

I'm currently building an ant simulator in python with pygame. The ants start in the middle and move on from there randomly. The movement works like this. Every few milliseconds `self.new_line` is set to True. Then a new `self.deltax` and `self.deltay` are calculated. Now, as long as `self.new_line` is False my ant will move with `self.x += deltax` and `self.y += deltay` per iteration. When `self.new_line` is True again the ant will start a new line with new values for `self.deltax` and `self.deltay`. The values for deltax and deltay are between -2 and +2 meaning the ant could move in every angle.

[Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exLqL.png)

[image]

Questions:

1. However i want my ants only to move in a specific angle. [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydmug.png)

[image]

How can i do this?

2. If you run the program with on ant you will see that the speed of the ant changes with new lines. How can make my ant to have one consistent speed?
3. How can i make my ant bounce of walls in a specific angle?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

These are multiple questions. The intent is to ask only one question. I will only answer 2 of them.
Use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) and [`rotate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate) to generate a direction vector with constant length and angle in a specified range:

```py
if self.new_line:
    angle = random.randint(-45, 45)
    direction_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(0, -self.VEL).rotate(angle)
    self.deltax = direction_vector.x
    self.deltay = direction_vector.y
```